# Trying to create eight methods and add them to a variable

Tags: javascript

BattleSimulation Class
 Add a function to the BattleSimulation class prototype called “createEnemies”. In this 
function, use a loop to create 20 Enemy instances and populate the Enemies array
property.
Add a function to the BattleSimulation class prototype called “createPlayers”. In this
function, do the following:
****Create eight Weapons objects. Create a variable called “weaponsCache” and add the
8 weapons you just created to it.****
I am stuck on the last step.

//Class for Battle Simulation object

```
class BattleSimulation {
    constructor() {
        this.player = [];
        this.enemies = [];
        this.createEnemies = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                this.enemies[i].Enemy;
            };
        };
    };
}
```

This is the whole code

```
//Start of program
//Class for the player object
class Player {
    constructor(name, weapons) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = 10;
        this.strength = 2;
        this.weapons = weapons;
        this.applyDamage = function(num) {
            this.health - num;
        };
        this.isAlive = function() {
            if (this.health > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            };
        };
        this.attackWith = function() {
            let randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 7);
            for (var i = randomNum; i < weapons.length; i++) {
                return weapons[i];
            };
        };
    };
}

//Class for the Weapon object

    class Weapon {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.damage = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            this.attack = function(player, enemy) {
                while (player.isAlive() & enemy.isAlive()) {
                    let totalDamage = 0;
                    totalDamage = player.strength * this.damage
                    enemy.applyDamage(totalDamage);
                    if (enemy.isAlive()) {
                        enemy.attack(player);
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    //Class for Enemy object
    class Enemy {
        constructor() {
            this.name = 'Enemy';
            this.health = 5;
            this.strength = 2;
            this.applyDamage = function(num) {
                this.health - num;
            };
            this.isAlive = function() {
                if (this.health > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                };
            };
            this.attack = function(player) {
                player.applyDamage(enemies.strength);
            }
        };
    }

    //Class for Battle Simulation object 
    class BattleSimulation {
        constructor() {
            this.player = [];
            this.enemies = [];
            this.createEnemies = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    this.enemies[i].Enemy;
                };
            };
        };
    }
```

Comment: Hint: You're already doing very similar things, for instance in `createEnemies`.

Comment: Side note: You don't put `;` after the blocks attached to control flow statements like `for`, `if`, `else`, `while`, and `switch`. You also don't put `;` after the constructor or method definitions in a `class` block. In both cases, it's harmless (in the former case because the language supports it via `EmptyStatement`, in the latter case because the grammar was explicitly written to tolerate this easy mistake), but it's not correct. Finally, if you find yourself writing `if (x > 0) { return true; } else { return false; }`, just write `return x > 0;`. :-) Happy coding!

Comment: thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: did you take a look at the problem I have? Thanks